# Matlab Error on integration

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to run this simple code :

```
test = int(h, h = 0..1); disp(test);
```

However Matlab tells me :

```
??? Error: File: Q1.m Line: 34 Column:
17
The expression to the left of the
equals sign is not a valid target for
an assignment.
```

(Column 17 corresponds to "h =")

(Rest of the program is mostly defining matrix and meshing them, if you need it, tell me.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this :

```
>> syms h
>> test = int(h, h,0,1)

test =

1/2
```

Comment: This works fine, thanks. Any explanation or documentation on why it does ?

Comment: @VictorAndrieu check the online mathworks [documentation](http://www.mathworks.in/help/symbolic/int.html), you must specify expression, variable and limits

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation for int() in matlab. If you trying to do what I think you are then you want

```
int(h, 0, 1)
```

More info: www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/int.html

Comment: This won't work either. You must specify both the expression and the integration variable: `int(h, h, 0, 1)`, just like [P0W](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1870232/p0w) described in his answer.

Comment: In the documentation, what I found was such kind of example :
int(exp(-x^2), x = 0..infinity)
http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/int.html

Comment: You're looking at the MuPAD documentation, which is a different program. There are ways to integrate it with matlab but you'll probably want to stick with the regular matlab functions for now.